# JDBC Source Connector - table.whitelist - 5 Tables in List - What is The Order of Execution

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have 5 tables listed in JDBC Source connector table.whitelist.  Are they all synced from PostgreSQL to Kafka in parallel or one table after the other.  If it is one table the other, what is the order (the order the tables are listed in table.whitelist?, alphabetically?). Is the order guaranteed?

Is there a way to guarantee the order?

Comment: They should make use of parallelism if configured correctly. But there's also a very important property to take into account - mode. Can be bulk, timestamp, incrementing, timestamp+incrementing. It's not about parallelism per se, but very important to set right in your case. What mode are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm using timestamp mode.  If all tables in table.whitelist run in parallel, can I assume that also tables in two different source connectors will run in parallel or when there are several source connectors whey run one after the other?  The reason I'm asking is because I have a table that I want to make sure it is running first.  Can I so something to make specific table run first before all other tables?